# Is it mold underneath my plaster wall?

Tags: mold, plaster, lath-and-plaster, wallpaper

I wanted to remove wallpaper from older home with horsehair plaster. I started feeling to see what’s underneath. It looks like specks but not sure what it is. Picture attached. Thanks!![image]

Comment: Will need to have it tested to know.  Even a mold expert seeing a picture will only say it is a possibility.

Comment: Can you post a better picture that is straight towards those spots? It actually looks more like an aggregate (small rocks) in the plaster, but I've never seen that.

Comment: Spray it with some bleach. If it is mold it will dye

Comment: Not likely. I think mold would grow in more irregularly-sized and/or irregularly-distributed patches. I think you'd see evidence of water damage to go along with it if it were mold, too. It seems to be a gravel-like substance embedded in the top layer of plaster. I lived in a house built in the 20s that had a plaster surface like that. It was skim-coated with "pure" plaster in most places though. Scraping at it will reveal if it's a surface thing like mold or rather particles embedded in the plaster.